# iMacros (Firefox) control via C#

Tags: c#, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I am working with iMacros (firefox) automation. So far I can open firefox, start macro. But I want that when iMacros finish its task. The browser closed. Is there anything that iMacro tell browser that its job done. Or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

For that I think you have to buy iMacros. It will give you some libraries that go with C# and enable using iMacros in C#. I've tried using the free version of iMacros and C# but it didn't work well for me. Some libraries were missing.

And to answer you question please use better English.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the commercial edition for this to work. If you have this version, then all you need to do is to use the "iimOpen" command to start IE, Firefox or Chrome, and then "iimPlay" to run the macro in the browser. The command returns with an status code once the macro is completed.

In the free Firefox edition, you can use Javascript for some in-browser automation.